# Determine filetype of path string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

**I need to decide the filetype of a file from the filename which I get in string.** So I decided to get the last three characters of the String to decide what filetype it is. How do I get the last three characters in a String. For example

```
var fileName = "test.pdf"
```

I need to get the **pdf** alone. **Is there any other better way to check for the file type other than this. Please suggest me that also.** Because I think, I won be able to recognise if the filetype comes in four characters like **"jpeg"** and other stuff. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I think you are looking for :

The path extension, if any, of the string as interpreted as a path. (read-only)
Declaration

Swift

```
var pathExtension: String { get }
```

Discussion

The path extension is the portion of the last path component which follows the final period, if there is one. The extension divider is not included. The following table illustrates the effect of `pathExtension` on a variety of different paths:

Receiver’s String Value

String Returned

“/tmp/scratch.tiff”   “tiff”

Example :

```
file.pathExtension
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/pathExtension

Comment: Thank you for mentioning whether the dot is included. The standard docs don't bother to mention it.

Answer (score 8):

As of Swift 2.x, `pathExtension` is no longer available for the `String` class.

You can instead cast to `NSString` and do:

```
let filename = "test.pdf"
let extension = (filename as NSString).pathExtension
```

Comment: I don't understand why Apple disable it and rollback to Objective-C NSString.

Answer (score 5):

```
let filename: String = "test.pdf"
let pathExtention = filename.pathExtension
```

Answer (score 0):

download [This File from DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z30no1mb5l55rba/UTI.swift?dl=0)
add to your Project and use like this

```
if let fileURL = URL(string: newURL){
        let fileUTI = UTI(withExtension: fileURL.pathExtension)
        switch fileUTI {
        case .pdf:
            print("add PDF Options")
            self.selecteFileMemeTyp = fileUTI.mimeType!
            self.addAllPDFOptions()
        case .jpeg:
            print("add jpg Options")
        case .png:
            print("add png Options")
        case .tiff:
            print("add tiff Options")
        case .gif:
            print("add gif options")
        case .spreadsheet:
            print("add excel Options")
        case .html:
            print("add html options")
        case .zipArchive:
            print("add zip Options")
            break
        case .docx , .doc:
            print("add dox options")
        default:
            print("default")
        } }
```